# Search paging not showing "last page" option

Tags: sharepoint-search

In OOTB Search result page, there is no "last page option". Any OOTB feature or web part to show "last page option" in SharePoint search page?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

OOTB, there is no option to enable that but you can modify the display template of the custom search web part (CSWP) with advanced paging methods as described in the post [here](https://sharepointinterface.com/2015/05/03/advanced-paging-with-sharepoint-content-search-web-part-display-templates/).

Basically, the display template contains `ctx.ListData` object which contains everything we need to implement an end-to-end paging system.

**Last page number for the result set**. This value (represented by the `lastPageNumber` variable) isn’t readily available in a way that can be “plucked” out of the search data, so the display template scripting simply does a little math to calculate it: `Math.ceil(totalRowCount /rowsPerPageCount)`.

In non-code terms: the last page of the total search results set is the total number of results in the set divided by the number of results displayed per page, rounded-down. As with the `firstPageNumber` and `firstPage` variables, don’t confuse `lastPageNumber` with the OOTB lastPage object reference.